# If a US tax resident buys some shares in a municipal money fund and sells them shortly after, do they incur any taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, mutual-funds, bond-funds, municipal-bonds

If a US tax resident buys some shares in a municipal money fund (e.g., Schwab Municipal Money Fund [SWTXX](https://www.schwabfunds.com/products/SWTXX)) and sells them shortly after, do they incur any taxes? The municipal money fund is advertised as tax-free but the holding period sometimes impacts the amount of taxes one has to pay on some financial products (e.g., for some [dividends](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Qualified_dividend&oldid=1118033165#:%7E:text=meet%20holding%20period%20requirements%3A%20you%20must%20have%20held%20the%20stock%20for%20more%20than%2060%20days%20during%20the%20121-day%20period%20that%20begins%2060%20days%20before%20the%20ex-dividend%20date)).

Answer (score 4):

In the US, taxes are usually on income, property or sale of goods or services. There are no taxes on transactions. So no, selling them doesn't incur any taxes.

.

.

.

Recognizing income does.

PS: Municipal money bonds are *not* tax free. They *produce* income which is tax *exempt*. I.e.: interest paid on these bonds is not subject to the Federal income tax (may be subject to State income tax, usually States only exempt their own bonds). You can still incur tax liability if you recognize income that is not exempt, such as capital gains for example.